# Can't style background color of selected drawer item

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml, android-theme, android-styles

I've tried looking through several SO answers for this question, but none of them seem to work for me.

I'm trying to change the background color of the selected item in my navigation drawer ([the gray](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hKzbb.png)).

Here is my code:

`menu_drawer`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_one"
            android:id="@+id/nav_first_fragment"
            android:title="One"
            android:checked="true"/>
        <item
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_two"
            android:id="@+id/nav_second_fragment"
            android:title="Two" />
        <item
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_three"
            android:id="@+id/nav_third_fragment"
            android:title="Three" />
    </group>
</menu>
```

`activity_main`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/appbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
            app:elevation="0dp">

            <include
                layout="@layout/toolbar"
                />

            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                />

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/pager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
            />

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nvView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        app:menu="@menu/menu_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check with this attribute

> itemBackground

Then in your color directory have an xml file, something like this

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:color="#c0c0c0" android:state_checked="true" />
<item android:color="#ffffff" />
</selector>
```

Then add to NavigationView

> app:itemBackground="@color/nv_list"

**Update:**

Check this [doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/NavigationView.html)

Comment: Where can I find the various states that the navigation drawer uses?

Comment: @user5382818, check the doc link

Answer (score 0):

Put below file to drawable folder :

list_selectoritem.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/list_item_bg_normal" android:state_activated="false"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/list_item_bg_pressed" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/list_item_bg_pressed" android:state_activated="true"/>

</selector>
```

list_item_bg_pressed.xml

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
  <gradient
      android:startColor="@color/list_background_pressed"
      android:endColor="@color/list_background_pressed"
      android:angle="90" />
</shape>
```

list_item_bg_normal.xml

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
  <gradient
      android:startColor="@color/list_background"
      android:endColor="@color/list_background"
      android:angle="90" />
</shape>
```

Put below code in color.xml

```
<color name="list_background">#E2231A</color>
<color name="list_background_pressed">#C4BEB6</color>
<color name="list_divider">#ffffff</color>
```

And then apply below changes to your drawer's listview;

```
<ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_slidermenu"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@null"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"       
        android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selectoritem"
        android:background="@color/list_background"/>
```